# How to revert change of ArrayList after using List.set() JAVA

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, random, bit

I have an ArrayList of items (each item with weight and profit):

ArrayList itemList: 
[{Weight: 3, Profit: 10}, {Weight: 15, Profit: 50}, {Weight: 7, Profit: 25}, {Weight: 6, Profit: 15}, {Weight: 4, Profit: 10}]

Then I have a random bitStrings representing which items to be taken given maximum weight to be taken is 20 (capacity = 20).

Let's say the initial random bits obtain is [1,1,0,0,0] which means Item 1 and Item 2 are taken which give:

TotalWeight = 3 + 15 = 18 [<= capacity]

Then I have a random bit to be flipped (if the bit is 1 -> 0, and if the bit selected to flip is 0 -> 1). Let's say the order to flip the bits is [3,2,1,4,0].

So firstly, the bit at index 3 will be flipped and count the total weight like this:

[1,1,0,**0**,0] --> [1,1,0,**1**,0]

Hence, the new bitstring after bit[3] flip: [1,1,0,1,0].

Then count the total weight again:

Total Weight of new bitstring = 3 + 15 + 6 = 24 [> capacity]

So the total exceeds capacity and I want the new bitstring to assign back to the previous bitstring before it is flip:

[1,1,0,**1**,0] --> return back to previous state: [1,1,0,**0**,0].

After return back to state: [1,1,0,0,0] the next bit will be flip from the order just now **[3,2,1,4,0]** but now I have to flip the bit at index 2 according to the order from left to right. This becomes:

From [1,1,0,0,0] --> flip bit[2]:

[1,1,**0**,0,0] --> [1,1,**1**,0,0]

Then do the same calculate weight etc.

if the total still exceeds it will return back to previous state but if it does not exceeds it will add the new solution to a new ArrayList.

I have done some codings on it but my problems are to get back to the previous state and at adding the accepted bit strings to ArrayList improve. It stores the latest updated solution only and the other accepted solutions is being replaced as shown in the output I obtain.

This is my codes:
'

```
  public class KnapsackHC {
    public static void main (String[] args){
    int n = 5, capacity = 20, pointer, toFlip;
    //Item items = new Item();
    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> currentSolution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> flipOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> improve = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    //ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    itemList = getProblem();
    solution = initialSolution(n);
    currentSolution = solution;
    flipOrder = randomFlipOrder(n);

    System.out.println("List of Items: " + itemList);
    System.out.println("Initial solution: " + solution);
    System.out.println("Current solution: " + currentSolution);
    System.out.println("Random order: " + flipOrder);

    for (int i = 0; i < flipOrder.size(); i++){
        int totalWeight = 0, totalProfit = 0;

        pointer = flipOrder.get(i);
        toFlip = solution.get(pointer);

        for (int j = 0; j < solution.size(); j++){
            if (solution.get(j) == 1){
                totalWeight += itemList.get(j).getWeight();
                totalProfit += itemList.get(j).getProfit();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Updated Solution: " + currentSolution);
        System.out.println("Total Weight Solution " + (i+1) + " : " + totalWeight + " | Total Profit Solution " + (i+1) + " : " + totalProfit);

        if (totalWeight <= capacity){
            System.out.println("----------NOT EXCEED-----------");
            currentSolution = solution;
            System.out.println("currentSolution BEFORE FLIP: " + currentSolution);
            improve.add(currentSolution);
            System.out.println("Improve: " + improve);

            if (toFlip == 1){
                solution.set(pointer, 0);
            }
            else if (toFlip == 0){
                solution.set(pointer, 1);
            }
            System.out.println("solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [" + flipOrder.get(i) + "] : " + solution);

            currentSolution = solution;
            //solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("----------EXCEED!!!!------------");
            //currentSolution = solution;
            System.out.println("currentSolution BEFORE FLIP {return back to previous state}: " + currentSolution);

            if (toFlip == 1){
                solution.set(pointer, 0);
            }
            else if (toFlip == 0){
                solution.set(pointer, 1);
            }
            System.out.println("solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [" + flipOrder.get(i) + "] : " + solution);

            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        }

    }

}
/*
public static ArrayList<Integer> calcFitness(ArrayList<Integer> currentSolution, ArrayList<Integer> solution, ArrayList<Item> itemList, int capacity){
    System.out.println("\nAfter Flip: " + solution);
    System.out.println("Current Solution: " + currentSolution);

    int totalWeight = 0; 
    int totalProfit = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < solution.size(); i++){
        if (solution.get(i) == 1){
            totalWeight += itemList.get(i).getWeight();
            totalProfit += itemList.get(i).getProfit();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total Weight: " + totalWeight + " || Total Profit: " + totalProfit);


    if (totalWeight <= capacity){
        currentSolution = solution;
        System.out.println("Solution change: " + currentSolution);
        System.out.println();
        return solution;
    }
    else{

        System.out.println("Solution NO change: " + currentSolution);
        System.out.println();
        return currentSolution;
    }

}*/

public static ArrayList<Item> getProblem(){
    ArrayList<Item> itemsArr = new ArrayList<Item>();

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("knapsack_problem_5.txt" ) );

        int i = 0;
        String str;
        while ( (str = in.readLine() )!= null ) {
            String[] item = str.split( "," );
            //System.out.print("Weight #" + i + " : " + Integer.parseInt(item[0]));
            //System.out.print("Profit #" + i + " : " + Integer.parseInt(item[1]));
            int weight = Integer.parseInt(item[0]);
            int profit = Integer.parseInt(item[1]);

            itemsArr.add(i,new Item(weight,profit));

            i++;
        }
        in.close();
    } catch ( IOException ex ) {
        System.err.println( "Error: Can't open the file for reading." );
    }

    return itemsArr;
}

//generate initial solution(bits) randomly
public static ArrayList<Integer> initialSolution(int length){
    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>(length);

    // generate some random boolean values
    boolean[] booleans = new boolean[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++) {
      booleans[i] = r.nextBoolean();
    }

    for (boolean b : booleans) {
      if (b == true){
          solution.add(1);
      }
      else{
          solution.add(0);
      }
    }

    return solution;

}

public static ArrayList<Integer> randomFlipOrder(int length){
    ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        order.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(order);

    return order;
   }
  }
```

'

My textfile consists the following (weight, profit):

3,10

15,50

7,25

6,15

4,10

My output obtained (the initial bit strings and random order to flip bit will be randomly generated):

List of Items: [{Weight: 3, Profit: 10}, {Weight: 15, Profit: 50}, {Weight: 7, Profit: 25}, {Weight: 6, Profit: 15}, {Weight: 4, Profit: 10}]

Initial solution: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Current solution: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Random order: [2, 4, 0, 1, 3]

Updated Solution: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Total Weight Solution 1 : 9 | Total Profit Solution 1 : 25

----------NOT EXCEED-----------

currentSolution BEFORE FLIP: [1, 0, 0, 1, 0]

Improve: [[1, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [2] : [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

---

Updated Solution: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

Total Weight Solution 2 : 16 | Total Profit Solution 2 : 50

----------NOT EXCEED-----------

currentSolution BEFORE FLIP: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]

Improve: [[1, 0, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]] **It doesn't store the previous accepted solution but replace it with new one**

solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [4] : [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

---

Updated Solution: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Total Weight Solution 3 : 20 | Total Profit Solution 3 : 60

----------NOT EXCEED-----------

currentSolution BEFORE FLIP: [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Improve: [[1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [0] : [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

---

Updated Solution: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Total Weight Solution 4 : 17 | Total Profit Solution 4 : 50

----------NOT EXCEED-----------

currentSolution BEFORE FLIP: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]

Improve: [[0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [1] : [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

---

Updated Solution: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Total Weight Solution 5 : 32 | Total Profit Solution 5 : 100

----------EXCEED!!!!------------

currentSolution BEFORE FLIP {return back to previous state}: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1]  **==> This should return back to [0,0,1,1,1] where the capacity is not exceeded**

solution AFTER FLIP from Random Order [3] : [0, 1, 1, 0, 1] **==> this should be flipped from [0,0,1,1,1] and bcomes -> [0,0,1,0,1]**

---

And lastly, once it has becomes [0,0,1,0,1] it should display the total weight again and display but it's not displaying.

I'm not sure where are the mistakes. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hint: this is really **a lot** of input. For your (and our sake that is) I would recommend to *reduce* the whole problem to its core. In other words: try to find a piece of example code that shows your problem (in other words: code that does something with a list) which comes without the "overhead" of weights, files, ... And side note: such code is really really perfect for TDD and unit testing. And doing TDD; you would start with small, working code; increasing that step by step. That works **much** better compared to pull together 100s lines of code ... to then figure: somewhere bug in there

Answer (score 0):

I have edited my code to make it shorter. I still haven't managed to get the previous bitstrings if the weight exceeds.

This is my updated codes:
'

```
  public class BitString {
    public static void main (String[] args){
    int n = 3, capacity = 11, pointer, toFlip;

    ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
    ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> currentSolution = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> flipOrder = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> improve = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

    itemList.add(new Item(4,5));
    itemList.add(new Item(10,12));
    itemList.add(new Item(5,8));

    solution = initialSolution(n);
    currentSolution = solution;
    flipOrder = randomFlipOrder(n);

    System.out.println("List of Items: " + itemList);
    System.out.println("Initial solution: " + solution);
    System.out.println("Current solution: " + currentSolution);
    System.out.println("Random order: " + flipOrder);

    for (int i = 0; i < flipOrder.size(); i++){
        int totalWeight = 0, totalProfit = 0;

        pointer = flipOrder.get(i);
        toFlip = solution.get(pointer);

        System.out.println();

        for (int j = 0; j < solution.size(); j++){
            if (solution.get(j) == 1){
                totalWeight += itemList.get(j).getWeight();
                totalProfit += itemList.get(j).getProfit();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Total Weight For Solution " + solution + " : " + totalWeight + " | Total Profit For Solution " + solution + " : " + totalProfit);

        if (totalWeight <= capacity){
            System.out.println(totalWeight + " NOT EXCEED CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: " + solution);
            currentSolution = solution;
            improve.add(currentSolution);
            System.out.println("Updated Current Solution: " + currentSolution);
            System.out.println("Updated Improved: " + improve);

            //do the flipping bits
            if (toFlip == 1)
                solution.set(pointer, 0);
            else
                solution.set(pointer, 1);

            System.out.println("New Solution After flip: " + solution);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println(totalWeight + " EXCEEDS CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: " + solution);
            solution = currentSolution;
            System.out.println("SOLUTION REVERTED: " + solution);

            //do the flipping bits
            if (toFlip == 1)
                solution.set(pointer, 0);
            else
                solution.set(pointer, 1);

            System.out.println("New Solution After flip: " + solution);
        }

    }

}

//generate initial solution(bits) randomly
public static ArrayList<Integer> initialSolution(int length){
    Random r = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> solution = new ArrayList<Integer>(length);

    // generate some random boolean values
    boolean[] booleans = new boolean[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < booleans.length; i++) {
      booleans[i] = r.nextBoolean();
    }

    for (boolean b : booleans) {
      if (b == true){
          solution.add(1);
      }
      else{
          solution.add(0);
      }
    }

    return solution;

}

   public static ArrayList<Integer> randomFlipOrder(int length){
    ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        order.add(i);
    }

    Collections.shuffle(order);

    return order;
   }
  }
```

'

And my output is:

List of Items: [{Weight: 4, Profit: 5}, {Weight: 10, Profit: 12}, {Weight: 5, Profit: 8}]

Initial solution: [0, 1, 0]

Current solution: [0, 1, 0]

Random order: [2, 0, 1]

Total Weight For Solution [0, 1, 0] : 10 | Total Profit For Solution [0, 1, 0] : 12

10 NOT EXCEED CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: [0, 1, 0]

Updated Current Solution: [0, 1, 0]

Updated Improved: [[0, 1, 0]]

New Solution After flip: [0, 1, 1]

Total Weight For Solution [0, 1, 1] : 15 | Total Profit For Solution [0, 1, 1] : 20

15 EXCEEDS CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: [0, 1, 1]

SOLUTION REVERTED: [0, 1, 1]

New Solution After flip: [1, 1, 1]

Total Weight For Solution [1, 1, 1] : 19 | Total Profit For Solution [1, 1, 1] : 25

19 EXCEEDS CAPACITY FOR SOLUTION: [1, 1, 1]

SOLUTION REVERTED: [1, 1, 1]

New Solution After flip: [1, 0, 1]